# How do I adapt my timestamp to MYSQL's DATETIME?

Tags: mysql, xml

Ok guys, I hope someone here can help me.

I got a bunch of XML files I have to import with this time format:

```
20100712 17:51:03
```

And according to the MYSQL [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html), the correct DATETIME format is:

```
'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'
```

As you can see, the only thing that is ruining the show for me is those hyphens between the year, month and date.

Would anyone know of a good tip to try to adapt this format to MYSQL's? I already tried importing it just like it is and MYSQL changes the date to 00-00-00 00:00:00 because it's in an invalid format.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date `STR_TO_DATE('20100712 17:51:03', '%Y%m%d %H:%i:%s')`

Comment: Didn't know Carl Sagan was on Stack Overflow...

Comment: Apparently I upset several people, I'm sorry my Google-fu didn't bring me up this easy solutions. Thanks everyone for the help anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try STR_TO_DATE:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date